# How to call form validity event if no input is entered

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple form with bootstrap which I need to validate before submitting. It has auto support for invalid-feedback. It looks like this

```js
let forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");
var productNameField = document.getElementById("productName");

productNameField.addEventListener("input", function () {
        var val = document.getElementById("productName").value;
        console.log("not entering here if I don't enter an input", val);
        if (!isValidString(val)) {
            productNameField.setCustomValidity("invalid");
        } else {
            productNameField.setCustomValidity("");
        }
    });
    
 
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener(
            "submit",
            function (event) {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    console.log("not valid");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                console.log("here validation");
                form.classList.add("was-validated");
            },
            false
        );
    });
```

```html
<form
                    action="/products/addProduct"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    class="needs-validation"
                    novalidate
                    method="post"
                >
                    <div class="col-md-12 position-relative">
                        <label for="productName" class="form-label"
                            >Product Name</label
                        >
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="productName"
                            id="productName"
                            class="form-control"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please provide a valid Product Name(at least two
                            characters, no special characters allowed).
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" id="savebutton" name="Submit">
                            Create
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Now when I type an input I immediately see an error if !validString (because of the input eventlistener). But if I just click on the submit button it is not calling the validString function.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const productNameField = document.getElementById("productName");
    
    const isInputValid = function() {
      return productNameField.value.length > 1;
    }
    const updateValidity = function() {
      if (isInputValid()) {
        productNameField.classList.remove('invalid')
      } else {
        productNameField.classList.add('invalid')
      }
    }
    
    productNameField.addEventListener("input", updateValidity);
    
    
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");
    
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener(
        "submit",
        function (event) {
          updateValidity();
          if (isInputValid()) {
            console.log("validation complete");
            form.classList.add("was-validated");
          } else {
            console.log("validation failed");
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      );
    });
```